# Is there a way to speed up a fetch from Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios

I already asked a similar question but still can't get it to work.  I have a core data database with 30k+ records.  I am trying to fetch it into a tableview.  I watched the WWDC presentation on core data and whatever the presenter suggested it didn't work for me.  I deleted most of the fields from that table and only left like 4 which contains nsstring and date.  I used setFetchBatchSize with different numbers and still when using instruments the fetch controller was fetching all 30k records.  I watched it over and still not sure what i am doing from to lower the fetch.  I used a separate thread and showed svprogreshud but that made it even slower i guess because the thread is not running right away.

Also The data is divided 12 sections and i have a field in core database for it with one character to set up sections.

I also set -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1  and when running on the device it showed 3sec loading that fetch request with all the records but showed
 CoreData: sql: pragma cache_size=200 
 CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 3.1087s for 36684 rows.

Here is some of the code

```
-(void)useDocument{

    if (self.peopleDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){
        [self.peopleDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            [self setupFetchResultsController];

        }];

    } else if (self.peopleDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal){
        [self setupFetchResultsController];
    }     
}

-(void)setupFetchResultsController
{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"people"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"pplicon" ascending:YES]];
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

    [request setFetchBatchSize:50];
    //[request setFetchLimit:100];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.peopleDatabase.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"pplicon" cacheName:@"peopleCache"]; 
}
```

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE
Jody thank you again for answering.
I went to the core data setup to the table and pplicon indexed is checked.  Do i need to check anything else.  I followed the directions for the wwdc video and ran instruments in core data fetches it shows NSManagedObjectContext executefetch .. Fetch Count 36684 and then another one with Fetch Count 12 Also in sampler the most time spent in  peopleviewcontroller setupfetchResultsContoroller 363.75ms and UIAplication Run 287.6ms. In activity Monitor the app takes up 91mb real memory.  Is there anyway to improve this time?  What else can i check and see where the hang up is?

As far as the sections.  I have a character in the database pplicon which used to show for section and the data is sort by it.

Data Model for now has one Entity with 5 Attribues as string and 1 Attribute as Date

Comment: It is impossible for us to help you without seeing the code you are using for the fetch.

Comment: I updated with code please let me know if i should post other parts of it.  Took of the threading part seems faster but freezes the app.  Thank you!!!

Comment: @kprobst Thanks for fixing up the code part.  I would like to know how to put all the code in there.  Every time i do copy and paste some code stays outside.

Comment: it would also help if we could see the data model.  Performance issues in core data are often related to data model more than the fetch.

Comment: @Yan No problem. You need to have a four-space indentation on the code blocks. There were just two or three braces in your code that didn't 'take' when you pasted them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have commented on a very similar question in the past.  You absolutely **must** run Instruments and see what it says.  It will tell you exactly where it is spending its time.

You are using sections, which can be expensive.  Is your section attribute "pplicon" setup in the database as an Index?  If not, you will most definitely have to scan all items in the database.  The only chance you have of not scanning all records is to make it an index.  The internals **may** be able to just use an index table to get the unique index values.  However, it still has to return section objects.

Again, you **must** turn on instruments while testing so you can see exactly where you are spending your time.

Comment: pplicon is one character long?  What are the difference in performance numbers if you do not use sections?  The numbers you posted do not make sense...  IIRC, you said it was taking seconds, and that data said its taking 1/3 of a second to load the fetch request...

Comment: I think what happend was that instruments was running on the emulator and the sql info was taken running from the device.  Which make sense.  In the emulator it loads in less then a sec and on iphone 4s will take about 3 sec  I am going to try to remove sections but before i implemented it wasn't much faster. The pplicon is just one unicode character that i use to section the data

Comment: This is an interesting issue.  Unfortunately, we are wasting time just bantering back and forth in comments.  I would be happy to discuss this in a chat room, or if you are willing, convert your entire database to JSON - very easy to do, and post it somewhere.  I will download it, work with it a bit, and we can conclude the question here.

Comment: That would be great if you are available in a chat room.  It is pretty hard for me to explain the issue.  Please let me know when you are there and i will connect to the chat room.  Thank you very much!

Comment: OK... I'm in the iPhone/iPad room... never used it before, so I hope it will work...

Comment: Hi Jody. I created a separate project so i can test out the core data code. If you still interested to check it out let me know i will give you a link to it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, send it to me and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks.  I would like to send you a link privately.  I can't find a way to do pm using stackoverflow.  Can you tell me where i can send it to you so you can download the project.

Comment: email sent.  You can delete the comment with your email address if you want.

Comment: I sent the email with the link.

Answer (score 0):

Are section names computed? When section names are computed, Core Data automatically fetches all of them and invoke section name to get sorting right.